# Emojicon Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I implemented the library in Android Studio in my dependencies:

```
dependencies { 
compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.0'
}
```

I also added  `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in the Android Manifest.xml file and   `tools:replace="android:icon"` in the  tag also in the Android_Manifest.xml file.

When I build the project this errors comes out:

> Error:(8) No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'emojiconAlignment' in package 'com.example.projectemojitest'

Here's the xml:

```
package="com.emojitest"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name=".ChatApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateAccount"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_account" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Please post your xml

Answer (score -1):

```
emojiconAlignment
```

make sure this does exists in your application and if it does then you should use

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to call the attributes for the library.